# Using formula for calculating values for another column using previous columns in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a system in which I am storing sessional formula of a particular teacher's subject like this:

```
sessional_formula
| teacher_id | course_code | course_dep | formula |
```

Assuming some value in formula for particular course_code and course_dep and teacher_id

I have a marks table in which I am storing marks of all students in one table:

```
marks
| roll_no | course_code | course_dep | class_test1 | class_test2 | class_test3 | sessional |
```

So, when and how should I calculate sessional marks based on the sessional formula Sessional(for some it can be Internals marks)
The sessional formula is such that it should be applied on all the class tests if they have been taken (I'm writing it in practical real process) and then produce sessional marks.

Comment: How will the formula look show some examples?

Comment: it can be anything.
Actually I'm taking from teacher, in input box.. so i'm pretty confused.. whether i should provide him input box or limited no. of select options so as I can use switch case to select formula.. what you'd prefered?

Comment: There are two ways to implement:One store formula as a type like 1,2,3 etc and since you tagged php you can use that to apply the suitable formula on marks based on the formula type and it's very easy to implement and the second option is to use prepared statements and also REGEXP to retrieve and evaluate the formula which is very difficult to implement.

Comment: okay! on the first phase i'll implement limited formulas.

Comment: Okay then change your db schema and store formula type as an integer and retrieve it using php and apply suitable formula on the retrieved marks to evaluate the results.If you want sample let me know.

Comment: When I'll be in trouble then surely will ask you ;)